# Awk - add a line, if and only if this line does not already exist

Tags: awk

I'd like use `awk` to parse a file, and add a line, if and only if this line does not already exist.

My file:

```
cccc
dddd
aaaa
mmm
```

*Example 1*: I'm looking for "**aaaa**"

"aaaa" exists so, nothing happens, the output file will be the same.

*Example 2*: I'm looking for "**bbbb**"

"bbbb" doesn't exist. My output file should be :

```
cccc
dddd
aaaa
mmm
bbbb
```

How can I obtain this result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ awk -v x='aaaa' '$0 == x {found=1} END {if(!found) print x} 1' file
cccc
dddd
aaaa
mmm

$ awk -v x='bbbb' '$0 == x {found=1} END {if(!found) print x} 1' file
cccc
dddd
aaaa
mmm
bbbb
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to handle this one at a time

```bsh
line=aaaa
grep -Fx -q "$line" file || echo "$line" >> file
```

If you know all the possibilities up front, then this may be more efficient:

```bsh
$ cat lines_to_add
aaaa
bbbb

$ grep -Fx -f file -v lines_to_add >> file

$ cat file
cccc
dddd
aaaa
mmm
bbbb
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU sed, this is a cool alternative:

```
$ sed -z '/bbbb/!s/$/bbbb\n/' file > file.out
$ cat file.out
cccc
dddd
aaaa
mmm
bbbb
```

The `-z` flag makes sed interpret the file as null-byte delimited instead of newline delimited. This way, all lines come into the pattern space at once and if the regex is not find in the whole file (`/bbbb/!`), the not-found line and a newline are appended to the end of the file (`s/$/bbbb\n/`). The last newline is required or the output file would not be a text file, according to the POSIX standard.

If you want to provide the line as a variable:

```
line=bbbb
sed -z /"$line"'/!s/$/'"$line"'\n/' file > file.out
```

Comment: You could avoid reading the whole file to memory by using something like:`sed -e '/aaaa/,${b};${s/$/\naaaa/}' file`.

Comment: @Isaac That is a nice idea! Very similar to what Rakesh's answer proposes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it with awk is to give input file twice.

```
$ awk '
  FNR == NR { next }
  /bbbb/, 0 { print; next }
  NR == 2*FNR { $0 = $0 ORS "bbbb"}1
' file file
```

Same method as above but with sed command:

```
sed -e '
  /bbbb/,$b
  $a bbbb
' file
```